# Annoying error while doing gradle build for multi-module spring boot proj

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot

All of a sudden I started to get this error from command line while doing:

gradle build:

```
org.gradle.cache.CacheOpenException: Could not open no_buildscript class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\Ext_jossef\IdeaProjects\notification_processor_servic
e\settings.gradle' (\\STORAGE\Users\Ext_jossef\.gradle\caches\2.2.1\scripts\settings_ckei5kxiw9x1b26ofzmlsiiy5\SettingsScript\no_buildscript).
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:48)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:28)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.doOpen(DefaultCacheFactory.java:80)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.open(DefaultCacheFactory.java:50)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheRepository$PersistentCacheBuilder.doOpen(DefaultCacheRepository.java:138)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheRepository$AbstractCacheBuilder.open(DefaultCacheRepository.java:121)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.compile(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:59)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.ShortCircuitEmptyScriptCompiler.compile(ShortCircuitEmptyScriptCompiler.java:36)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.CachingScriptClassCompiler.compile(CachingScriptClassCompiler.java:37)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.DefaultScriptCompilerFactory$ScriptCompilerImpl.compile(DefaultScriptCompilerFactory.java:64)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:141)
        at org.gradle.initialization.ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.applySettingsScript(ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.java:72)
        at org.gradle.initialization.ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.process(ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.java:62)
        at org.gradle.initialization.PropertiesLoadingSettingsProcessor.process(PropertiesLoadingSettingsProcessor.java:37)
        at org.gradle.initialization.SettingsHandler.findSettingsAndLoadIfAppropriate(SettingsHandler.java:89)
        at org.gradle.initialization.SettingsHandler.findAndLoadSettings(SettingsHandler.java:46)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:121)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.filelock.LockStateAccess.tryLock(LockStateAccess.java:83)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.filelock.LockFileAccess.tryLockState(LockFileAccess.java:83)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.lockStateRegion(DefaultFileLockManager.java:312)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:255)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.<init>(DefaultFileLockManager.java:127)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:80)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:67)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.open(DefaultCacheAccess.java:86)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:46)
        ... 38 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.739 secs
```

I tried everything.. restart the comp, re-import the project re-install gradle, delete gradle cache directory

I am doing the build using windows

However when I try to do gradle build from intelij plugin it seems to work but when I go straight to the command line it doesnt
I tried to do it while shutting down Intelij - Still same error

Any leads about that? thank you

Comment: Is `\\STORAGE` a network drive? Could be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21894715/how-do-i-fix-an-overlappingfilelockexception-when-building-with-gradle-on-window

Comment: I have no idea why it goes to STORAGE? I am working locally. what should I check? it never was network drive before

Comment: Any idea man? thats desperate