# Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to lock usage tracking spool file

Tags: java, android, gradle, build.gradle

Having problems while building an android application with gradle, here is the error i get when building it;

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to lock usage tracking spool file
            at com.android.tools.analytics.JournalingUsageTracker.newTrackFile(JournalingUsageTracker.java:98)
            at com.android.tools.analytics.JournalingUsageTracker.<init>(JournalingUsageTracker.java:78)
            ... 121 more
    Caused by: java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
            at com.android.tools.analytics.JournalingUsageTracker.newTrackFile(JournalingUsageTracker.java:95)
            ... 122 more
```

Here is my gradle details: https://pastebin.com/6v0dk5in

```
 ./gradlew --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.3.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2017-11-08 08:59:45 UTC
Revision:     e4f4804807ef7c2829da51877861ff06e07e006d

Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_66 (Oracle Corporation 25.66-b17)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.11 x86_64
```

Answer (score 1):

Killing the java process and re-building fixes it but you have to do this on every build.

os x el capitan 10.11 (15A284)

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/937

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

Answer (score 0):

I found these two other Stackoverflow threads that were helpful:

- [How do I fix an OverlappingFileLockException when building with Gradle on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21894715/how-do-i-fix-an-overlappingfilelockexception-when-building-with-gradle-on-window)
- [Android studio, configure gradle project takes forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21781569/android-studio-configure-gradle-project-takes-forever/21815505)

The issue in this case was that the Gradle Daemon was holding onto a file lock and subsequent builds were failing. This Gradle issue provided a more sustainable workaround:

[Gradle daemon locks files by leaving file handles open](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/937)

> Disable the daemon by adding `org.gradle.daemon=false` to `gradle.properties`

There are quite a few other variations on how to disable the [Gradle build in the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon)

The Gradle Daemon is useful for making builds faster by avoiding restarting the JVM and reloading the Gradle jar, and also by caching information.